# SQLite get second to last element

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have to get two last elements from table (or just id). My element's id is increased but not increment (next value is always larger but it is possible that more than 1 - elements are created by someone else and I am not supposed to modified them).

I know how to id it for last one:

```
public Long getLastDay(){
Cursor cursor= mDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS, new String[]{"MAX(" + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID + ")"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return (cursor.getLong(0));
    }
    return Long.parseLong("0");
}
```

For example for ids:

`1 4 7 11 14 15 19 25 28`

I want to get `28` (it works) and `25`.

How is it possible to get the second value?

**@EDIT:**

My code is:

```
 public Long getSecondLastDay(){
        Cursor cursor= mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT "+DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID+" FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS+ " LIMIT 2", null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return (cursor.getLong(0));
        }
        return Long.parseLong("0");
    }
```

Comment: `cursor.moveToLast();cursor.moveToPrevious();`...in order...

Comment: just select `COLUMN_DAY_ID` (not MAX of that column) and limit the result to two items ("LIMIT 2"), see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) for more info

Comment: @pskink Could you please explain me what to do with cursor? Should I use something like  `Cursor cursor= mDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS, new String[]{"SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID + " LIMIT 2"}, null, null, null, null, null);` ? Or where is this value?

Comment: I edited my post and put there code, if use `.moveToFirst` I get the last item (with largest id), if user `.moveToLast` there is still not second to last element. Is something wrong wih my code? @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the days in the reverse direction, and then just take the first two rows:

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS,
        new String[]{ DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID },
        null, null, null, null,
        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID + " DESC",
        "2");
long secondToLastDay = 0, lastDay = 0;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    lastDay = cursor.getLong(0);
    if (cursor.moveToNext())
        secondToLastDay = cursor.getLong(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use cursor.moveToLast and then cursor.moveToPreviuous

Comment: User cursor.moveToLast(); then cursor.moveToPrevious() and then System.out.println(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(your column))    Tell me what return.